Sambashare with wifi hotspot
I have my computer with sambashare and an androidTV from which I want to view the contents of shared folders.
It all works as expected when they both are connected to an "intermediary network" (e.g. my router or hotspot on my phone), but when I connect the TV to the hotspot launched on the pc, the TV does not recognise that there is a samba connection.
It's not the TV's fault, because I also cannot view my folders via phone if connected directly to pc's hotspot.
How do I make it work?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
